# In Jmeter websocket testing, after the websocket text frame filter getting applied - Websocket I/O error is shown

Tags: websocket, jmeter

Though Websocket text frame filter is getting applied, getting an Read timed out error and am not able to proceed further with execution.
When checked in jmeter logs it was mentioned as "**DEBUG e.l.w.WebSocketClient: WebSocket client is being garbage collected; underlying TCP connection will be closed**"

How can I reconnect to the websocket existing connection?
why the read timed out error occurs even when executing the test with single user? Does it depend upon the load or any other parameter?

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/):

> Each JMeter (ThreadGroup) thread can have at most one active WebSocket connection. In the sampler, you can indicate whether you want to (re) use the current connection, or create a new one. If you create a new one, the current connection is closed at TCP level, but no WebSocket close frames are sent. If you want to close the connection properly (i.e. send a WebSocket close frame and wait for the close response), use the WebSocket Close sampler.

If the connection times out it's getting closed, you won't be able to "reconnect" to it.

In general you can create the websocket connection using the WebSocket Open Connection sampler:

[image]

and then tick "use existing connection" box in the Sampler you're using:

[image]

More information: [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers)

With regards to read timing out we cannot help really, I can only suggest using a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to capture WebSocket requests from JMeter and from the browser (or other application), JMeter's network footprint needs to be exactly the same, once you will send the same request you will get the same response.